# Sharing Video to facebook via FB SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

I have a video created in my app.
I want to shared this video to user's Facebook wall via facebook native SDK.
I am able to get the video sharing working, but there is no preview/share dialog shown to the user before sharing. The video is directly posted to user's wall.
Here is my code to get open an active session

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error){}
```

Once I get the session active, I call the below method to share the video

```
- (void)sendVideoFeedRequestWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
{
// create the connection object
FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

// create a handler block to handle the results of the request
FBRequestHandler handler =
^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // output the results of the request
    [self requestCompleted:connection result:result error:error];
};

// create the request object, using the /me as the graph path
FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me/videos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// add the request to the connection object, if more than one request is added
// the connection object will compose the requests as a batch request; whether or
// not the request is a batch or a singleton, the handler behavior is the same,
// allowing the application to be dynamic in regards to whether a single or multiple
// requests are occuring
[newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];

// if there's an outstanding connection, just cancel
[self.requestConnection cancel];

// keep track of our connection, and start it
self.requestConnection = newConnection;
[newConnection start];

}
```

The params I am sending to this method are:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"video.mov",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                               @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                               nil];
```

This works well as far as posting the video is concerned. But, I want a share/preview dialog to be shown.
Anybody got any hints on how to get it done?

Comment: Please check it here with new facebook SDK

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29427089/2787452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create something yourself or search for an existing solution on github (or similar). Something like a custom alert view where you can allow the user to enter text, have a thumbnail of the video which plays when tapped and a couple of buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Had to go like this way only.