# How to share NSData or phasset video using Facebook iOS SDK 4.0 FBSDKShareDialog

Tags: ios, facebook, video, nsdata

I noticed you can share NSData video to facebook messenger simply:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localVideoUrl];
[FBSDKMessengerSharer shareVideo:videoData withOptions:options];
```

But I’m having difficulties doing the same when sharing to facebook feed 
using local video file or phasset.

```
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [FBSDKShareVideo videoWithVideoURL:localVideoUrl];
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
[content setVideo: video];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:nil withContent:content delegate:self];
```

*com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Only asset file URLs are allowed for the native dialog*

How would I go about having similar nice app-switching behavior using phasset video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

With the new Facebook SDK 4.0, videos must be passed as assets URL. You have to copy your local video path to Assets Library and use that generated URL to share on Facebook.

Step 1:

```
NSURL *videoURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_1007" ofType:@"mp4"]];
[self saveToCameraRoll:videoURL];
```

Step 2:

```
- (void)saveToCameraRoll:(NSURL *)srcURL
{
    NSLog(@"srcURL: %@", srcURL);

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock videoWriteCompletionBlock =
    ^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library %@", newURL.absoluteString);
            url_new  = newURL;
        }
    };

    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:srcURL])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:srcURL
                                    completionBlock:videoWriteCompletionBlock];
    }
}
```

Step 3:

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];    
NSURL *videoURL = url_new;
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoURL;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];   
content.video = video;
shareDialog.shareContent = content;
shareDialog.delegate = self;
[shareDialog show];
```

If you have any other query please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That would work, but the video that I’d like to share already exists in photo library since its an PHAsset. I wouldn’t want to create another copy. I can save PHAsset video locally temporarily (how I solved few other related sharing problems) or use its data. But there’s not really a way to bridge PHAsset to ALAsset to my knowledge? There’s no way to share PhotoKit videos using Facebook SDK 4.0 FBSDKShareDialog?

Comment: This is the new url generated!! `assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=E121FF88-B0AB-4EE9-BD60-E676617BDC54&ext=mp4`

Comment: It is possible to do this below without showing any modal and put description and title to the video?

Comment: I don't think you can override modal presenting style and attach any text or link using Sharing Dialogs.

Comment: if i want share video from my own server url like- http://www.myownserverurl.com/myvide.mp4  what to do?

Comment: sharing video from `PHAsset` is working if you use the url generated from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887638/how-to-get-an-alasset-url-from-a-phasset

Answer (score 0):

Please check: 1)The videos must be less than 12MB in size. 2)People who share should have Facebook for iOS client installed, version 26.0 or higher.

You should use the below line:

```
NSURL *movieUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

instead of

```
NSURL *movieUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```