# Error on Facebook Video Sharing IOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share a video on Facebook, I'm using fbsdk new version [4.1.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios) i have also followed the instruction given in developer.facebook.com

- The videos must be less than 12MB in size.
- People who share should have Facebook for iOS client installed, version 26.0     or higher.

I have used the following code to share a video in facebook

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc]init];

NSURL *videoURL=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoURL;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;

shareDialog.shareContent = content;
shareDialog.delegate=self;
[shareDialog show];
```

but the issue im getting is,

`Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 2.)" UserInfo=0x174479f40 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentValueKey=<FBSDKShareVideoContent: 0x174475040>, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Only asset file URLs are allowed for the native dialog., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=videoURL}`

Thanks

Comment: I think this may help you 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386478/how-to-share-nsdata-or-phasset-video-using-facebook-ios-sdk-4-0-fbsdksharedialog

Comment: Not work for me.. Can you tell me what you do?

Answer (score 0):

Use [UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL](http://iswwwup.com/t/d812a30a9e38/ios-fbsdksharedialog-share-dialog-not-open-for-video-sharing.html) instead of UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL.